# Does std::promise internally use std::condition_variable to notify the associated std::future?

Tags: c++, condition-variable, std-future

My question is does `std::promise` notify the associated `std::future` through using a `std::condition_variable`?

I search the source code of `std::promise` and found this [website](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/future.html). But I didn't see `std::promise` has `std::condition_variable` in its member data.

Comment: The standard library does whatever is needed to make things work. The standard usually does not specify that it must, or must not, use some specific APIs internally to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, I understand standard only specifies the required functionality and leaves the implementation to developers. But is it possible to know how GCC implements `std::promise`?

Comment: Yes sure, just read the source. Note this is not what you have asked.

Comment: Could you please point out the source?  I only found the website in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking where to download the source of gcc? Have you tried to google "download gcc source"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an answer for libc++.

A search for `condition_variable` in [`<future>`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/future#L536) returned exactly one result:

```
// lines 531 -- 538
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_FUTURE __assoc_sub_state
    : public __shared_count
{
protected:
    exception_ptr __exception_;
    mutable mutex __mut_;
    mutable condition_variable __cv_;
    unsigned __state_;
```

Here `__assoc_sub_state` is introduced. It is the base class for `__assoc_state`:

```
// lines 617 -- 619
template <class _Rp>
class _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_FUTURE __assoc_state
    : public __assoc_sub_state
```

And finally, `__assoc_state<_Rp>*` is both a member of `future<_Rp>`:

```
// lines 1082 -- 1085
template <class _Rp>
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_FUTURE future
{
    __assoc_state<_Rp>* __state_;
```

and a member of `promise<_Rp>`:

```
// lines 1360 -- 1363
template <class _Rp>
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_FUTURE promise
{
    __assoc_state<_Rp>* __state_;
```

So yeah, libc++ `std::promise` internally uses a `std::condition_variable` to notify the  associated `std::future`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!    I have another question: I check the `sizeof(std::condition_variable)` and `sizeof(std::promise<void>)` and the outputs are 48 and 24. Why is the size of `std::promise` smaller?     I am quite confused as I assume the size of a class should be larger than its member data.

Comment: @Tes `__asoc_state` is a shared state, so `promise` only holds a pointer to it.

Comment: I see. Very appreciate your patience and answering!